# How to output a long dictionary in a pandas dataframe column in its entirety?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with rather long dictionaries in one column.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
D = [[{'a':'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','b':'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'}]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D)
print df[0]
```

Which leads to this output:

```
0    {u'a': u'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', u'...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Everything but the start of the dictionary is omitted with ellipses.

How do I output the full dictionary without iterating over the individual keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
In[6]:df[0].values
Out[6]: array([ {'a': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'b': 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'}], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
D = [[{'a':'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','b':'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'}]]
print D[0][0]
```